# how to fix error when importing geopandas in Spyder, possibly due to qgis install?

Tags: python, virtualenv, spyder, geopandas, qgis

I run Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and use a virtualenv for Python (3.6.9) and use Spyder (3.6) as an IDE. I've set my Python interpreter on Spyder to point to this virtualenv and I've successfully used geopandas before with this setup. But now I am getting an import error when using Spyder.

```
import geopandas as gpd
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-a62d01c1d62e>", line 1, in <module>
    import geopandas as gpd

  File "/home/theuser/.virtualenvs/mypython3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries  # noqa

  File "/home/theuser/.virtualenvs/mypython3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/geoseries.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyproj import CRS, Transformer

ImportError: cannot import name 'CRS'
```

If I do the same thing in a terminal (after activating the virtualenv) I get no error. I've double-checked to make sure Spyder is still set to use the virtualenv for the interpreter.

The only thing I can think of that has "changed" between the last time I imported geopandas successfully in Spyder and now is that I have installed `qgis` using the quickstart instructions found [here](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html).

Please let me know if I can clarify anything about my setup or problem.

**UPDATE**

So I think I determined what was happening. When I install `qgis`, it installs other packages like `pyproj`, which have versions that conflict with the ones in my `virtualenv`. For some reason, when I import `geopandas` from spyder, it doesn't use `pyproj` from my virtualenv, but the other one installed with qgis, causing the error. I'm not sure why Spyder and/or geopandas would be importing the `pyproj` package outside the virtualenv.

For now, I've tried uninstalling the `pyproj` package installed with `qgis`, though this may cause problems when I use `qgis`. If someone has a better suggestion, I'd be open to it and I'd also like to know why when importing geopandas in Spyder it doesn't use the `pyproj` package in the virtualenv even though it uses the `geopandas` package from my virtualenv.

**UPDATE 2**
So Spyder's `sys.path` is different from the one I get when I use the my `virtualenv` from terminal. It includes `/use/lib/python3/dist-packages`, which is where `pyproj` is installed when I install `qgis`.

So when I import geopandas, and it imports `pyproj` it grabs this one. How can I get Spyder to check my `virtualenv` packages first?

Comment: I've confirmed it has something to do with `qgis` being installed. After uninstalling `qgis` I no longer get this import error.

Comment: Voting to close this question as it fundamentally comes down to how to run spyder with a virtual environment and managing paths.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I think the problem is we don't activate virtualenvs (because there's no simple, standard way to do that for Windows, Linux and Mac) and that seems to be required to drop `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` from `sys.path`. However, we do activate conda envs, so my recommendation is to use Anaconda instead.